# Configure a Pipenv environment in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pipenv

I am trying to add pipenv in project interpreter in pycharm but it throws an error.

These are the step that I followed :

-1- First in the command prompt I installed `pip install pipenv`

-2- Go to the directory of my project in the command prompt and typed `pipenv shell` (This command will look for the pipenv environment and load it, otherwise if not existing will create a new one)

-3- To install the last successful environment recorded (all packages and dependencies) typed `pipenv install --ignore-pipfile` to install production environment

-4- In PyCharm File->Settings->Project: ProjectName->Project Interpreter `click  add`
[image]

-5- select `pipenv environment`, pycharm automatically shows pipenv executable
[image]

-6- Press OK - What am I miising here?
I installed pipeline globally and on my project directory 
[image]

Runing pipenv shell on project directory shows this

```
Shell for C:\Users\gh8001\.virtualenvs\churn_prediction-UB3VC30i already activated.
No action taken to avoid nested environments.
```

Answer (score 3):

In step 3, once you used 'pipenv install --ignore-pipfile' you already created a virtual environment. You need to get pycharm to use this existing virtual environment (not create a new virtual env). So, in step 5, instead of selecting 'pipenv environment', which seeks to create a new virtual env (and which I find doesn't work well for specifying exact python versions well), do this instead:

- select 'Virtualenv Environment' tab
- then 'Existing Environment' button
- then point to the interpreter you created in step 3. You can find this interpreter by using 'pipenv --venv' for the root env directory, and then add /bin/python to the end.
- Select OK, and the new pipenv should be in use

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I spend half a day and finally found that the problem is in the stage of installing python.

Just uncheck the `Install launcher for all users(recommended)`

[image]

This option saves some of the python files such as pipenv.exe in the root `C:\Users\your_pc\AppData\Roaming\` and causes the problem.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

pipenv executable should point to a pipenv.exe file, not a python.exe file. I don't know why pycharm would incorrectly detect this.

Answer (score -3):

I think you may install pipenv using pip in anaconda. So you can find you pipenv executable in your anaconda/bin directory.